# Python 3 subprocess module throws error running "dir" on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

This simple program in `Python 3` throws errors. What could be the reason? This problem arose after I installed/reinstalled `Python 3.5/3.6`. Also `Python 2.7` is installed on my PC (windows 10 machine).

```
import subprocess 
out = subprocess.check_output(['dir'])
```

The error message:

> File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
>       **kwargs).stdout
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Answer (score 3):

It's not an executable, but [built-in](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) to the shell. Python subprocess module can't find it, so you got an error.

If you would like to play with subprocess module, use some existing binary, e.g. `python`, `notepad` or `ping`.
In case you need to list folder content, please use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @grundic

> It's not an executable, but [built-in](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) to the shell. [...]

If you really want to execute cmd built in commands, you have to execute `cmd.exe /c COMMAND_HERE` in your case:

```
import subprocess 
out = subprocess.check_output(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'dir'])
```

`/c` means that `cmd.exe` closes after execution

Comment: How about following:

out = subprocess.check_output(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'snap', 'network', 'ping'])

Comment: You have to specify the full path to `snap` if you want to run a not built-in command, but be aware of \ in Windows. For example running Python `out = subprocess.check_output(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'C:\\Program Files\\python\\python.exe'])`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "dir" is not in your path. I do not know the full path of this executable on Windows but maybe you should replace dir by c:\windwos\system\dir

Or a best solution would be to use functions in the os modules to list directories:

```
os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: It gives the same error even after replacing by c:\windwos\system\dir. Basically what I am doing is to run some shell commands for a shell based utility. I could run commands like mentioned below previously. I don't know what was changed during install/uninstall.
<pre>
import subprocess

cmd_find_nodes = ['snap', 'network', 'ping']

result = subprocess.check_output(cmd_find_nodes)

Comment: The problem was solved by adding the environment variables. Added C:\Python35\Scripts\; C:\Python35\; in the Path variable.